# Unable to run Edge under watir 6.10.3: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unexpected response, code=500, content-type="text/plain"

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, microsoft-edge

I have a simple code and similar code for `:chrome`, `:ie`, `:ff` works fine.

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.new :edge
```

My environment:

- ruby 2.4
- watir 6.10.3
- selenium-webdriver 3.11
- proper webdriver is downloaded and put into path (I matched the system version with the version of the driver)

As result I got error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unexpected response, code=500, content-type="text/plain"  
Unknown error  
    from c:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:88:in `create_response'
    from c:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:104:in `request'
    from c:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from c:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:164:in `execute'
    from c:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:97:in `create_session'
    from c:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/edge/driver.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from c:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:54:in `new'
    from c:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:54:in `for'
    from c:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:85:in `for'
    from c:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/browser.rb:48:in `initialize'
    from (irb):19:in `new'
    from (irb):19
    from C:/Ruby24/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

What's wrong?

UPDATE: This code works fine for EDGE at home, but fail at workstation. It seems some network or security configuration

Comment: Try running with: `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug` it might give you more details about what the underlying problem is.

Comment: Thanks. It helps find a solution. Microsoft Web Driver can’t be used with the Built-In Administrator account or while User Account Control is turned off. So I enable User Account Control, and now it works